# Code to reverse a word

Tags: python

I made this to reverse a word but am unable to plzz help.

```
while True:
    word = input("Normal Word: ")
    newWord = ""
    for i in range(len(word)):
        newWord += word[len(word)-(i+1)]
    print("Reversed Word: '" + newWord() + "'\n")
```

The error says
        "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

Comment: to reverse the words you can simple do `word[::-1]`, but in your case simple remove the `()` from `newWord()` it need to be `newWord`

Comment: What ***is*** wrong with the code? Does it throw an error? Does it produce incorrect output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python)

Comment: plzz help me plzz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your code is:

Calling `newWord()` in the print function instead of simply `newWord`.

---

```
while True:
    word = input("Normal Word: ")
    newWord = ""
    for i in range(len(word)):
        newWord += word[len(word) - (i + 1)]
    print("Reversed Word: '" + newWord() + "'\n")
```

---

A possibly more Pythonic solution is:

```
newWord = word[::-1]
print(newWord)
```

Comment: Yes `newWord` is not callable that is the error as I guess you mean in 2. For 1, they presumably want multiple words (and `break` on some condition), and I don't follow 3.

Comment: @Chris_Rands, you're right! Just edited the post.